# Hide the button which is available in p tag which is last of li tag

Tags: jquery

I am placing three buttons in one li (there are 4 p tags in one li tag) of last p tag. I need to catch the last p tag's second button. Please suggest some solution to do this.

Comment: If you can post some HTML, it might help!

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the second button in the last P tag:

```
$('p:last :button').eq(1).attr("id")
```

And if you want to hide it:

```
$('p:last :button').eq(1).attr("id").hide();
```